# Intuition for branch uniqueness in inner model theory

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, soft-question, large-cardinals, inner-model-theory

In inner model theory, what is the intuition behind the expectation that under appropriate conditions, we should have a single preferred branch to continue an iteration at a limit stage?

At the level of Woodin cardinals (or just multiple strong cardinals), inner model theory uses iteration trees rather than just linear iterations of models.  Proving iterability is (believed to be) the main problem for extending inner model theory to superstrong cardinals (and somewhat beyond, such as subcompact cardinals).  Key to iterability proofs appears existence of unique preferred branches.  Below (essentially) Woodin cardinals, 'preferred' can simply be 'with a well-founded limit', but it gets harder for stronger models; and beyond a certain level, we only have proofs conditional on, for example, some version of the Unique Branch Hypothesis.

Which leads us back to the question as to why we expect uniqueness, at least below models with long extenders.  A three word answer may be "canonicity implies uniqueness", but I would like to hear from experts in more detail.